# How should you handle jQuery utilizing soon-to-be deprecated methods on the Chrome browser?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, svg, npm, deprecation-warning

I have some NPMs which have dependencies that are using jQuery to make selections on SVG Elements. Below is the warning I receive when my NPMs use jQuery to make SVG selections.

---

> 'SVGElement.offsetWidth' is deprecated and will be removed in M50, around April 2016. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5724912467574784 for more details.
>   locuslabs.js:6635 'SVGElement.offsetHeight' is deprecated and will be removed in M50, around April 2016. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5724912467574784 for more details.

Chrome had suggested the following:

> "These attributes should only be supported on HTMLElement, but have
>   been supported on all Elements in WebKit and Blink.
>   getBoundingClientRect() can typically be used as a replacement."
>   -philipj@opera.com

Here is the section of jQuery code that creates this particular warning.

```
function getWidthOrHeight( elem, name, extra ) {
// Start with offset property, which is equivalent to the border-box value
var valueIsBorderBox = true,
    val = name === "width" ? elem.offsetWidth : elem.offsetHeight,
    styles = getStyles( elem ),
    isBorderBox = jQuery.css( elem, "boxSizing", false, styles ) === "border-box";
...
```

---

***The Question:***

Does NPM provide a way to modify which version of jQuery a NPM uses as a dependency? Is that the best approach to this problem, or should I be going about a resolution for this differently? To clarify, this is less of a technical question and more of a best implementation question.

Comment: I changed to outer xml in my code and the message went away. Not sure if it means anything.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to something that is open sourced, it's often a good idea to review their issue threads for your problem. If you don't find your problem being described, create a new issue. Then you can focus on updating the open source library instead of forcing a sort of polyfill workaround for a library using a deprecated method.

---

This issue is being reviewed and tracked on jQuery's Github Issue Thread:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2895

---

Update with result of review:

> *It seems no one really needs an offsetParent equivalent in non-legacy APIs so I'll close this issue. We don't support SVG nodes with a few exceptions and since offsetParent was never implemented in every popular browser, no web-facing code should depend on it.*

> *a crash, or even an exception, won't happen when these attributes are removed. What will happen is that if you're using jQuery older than 2.2.0, the :visible selector will match no SVG element and :hidden will match all SVG elements, i.e. SVG elements are always considered hidden.*
>
> *With jQuery 2.2.0 ([79bcb29](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/79bcb291324167ab2d844027d0cdc6300613d010)) this has been fixed and you shouldn't need to do anything at all.*